# Summing numbers in parallel takes twice as long as the serial version

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I have a `const LONGLONG UPPER = 1000000000;` in my code, and I'm trying to calculate the sum of all the numbers from 1 to `UPPER` (yes, I know there's a formula for this).

These are my globals:

```
const LONGLONG UPPER = 1000000000;
const int NUM = 10; // number of threads
LONGLONG g_sum;
CRITICAL_SECTION cs_sum;
```

This is my thread function:

```
DWORD WINAPI SumThread(PVOID pvParam) {
    LONGLONG i;
    LONGLONG sum = 0;
    LONGLONG x = (LONGLONG)pvParam;

    x = x * (UPPER / NUM);

    for (i = x + 1; i <= x + UPPER / NUM; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }

    EnterCriticalSection(&cs_sum);
    g_sum += sum;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs_sum);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the code I use to do the calculations:

```
HANDLE* hThreads = (HANDLE*)(malloc(sizeof(HANDLE) * NUM));
g_sum = 0;

InitializeCriticalSection(&cs_sum);
for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    hThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SumThread, (PVOID)i, 0, NULL);
}

WaitForMultipleObjects(NUM, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
DeleteCriticalSection(&cs_sum);
```

But I'm getting weird results: when I sum the numbers in a simple (serial) `for` loop, it's twice as fast as the multithreaded version. When I multiply `UPPER` by 10 and increase the number of threads to 40, the multithreaded version doesn't even stop (after 20 or so minutes). What's the reason for this?

Comment: What happens if you only use a number of threads equal to the number of cores or the number of cores minus 1?

Comment: I have 2 physical and 4 logical processors - I get the same results with 2, 3, and 4 threads.

Comment: Somewhat related, there are *much* faster ways of computing a sequential sum. Think about this: 1-through-10. That would be the same as (1+10) + (9+2) + (8+3) + (7+4) + (6+5). In other words, it is 11 * 5 = 55. One multiplication rather than 9 additions, and most importantly, *no loop*. Consider how you would apply that to your overall task.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I'm familiar with the formula, but I'm doing this as an exercise.

Comment: Ah ok. So long as this isn't for something critical. gotcha.

Comment: Is the sum-result correct regardless of the number of thread?

Comment: Yes, both methods arrive at the same result, regardless of the number of threads.

Comment: "When I multiply UPPER by 10 and ...  doesn't even stop"  How did you multiply by 10? `1000000000*10` or append a zero?  The first overflows.

Comment: Appended a zero. At any rate, issues like that would be caught fairly quickly, because I run the serial version before I run the multithreaded version.

Comment: `1000000000` needs to be `1000000000LL` then

Comment: @NathanOliver I changed it but I'm getting the same results (both in terms of the calculation itself and the elapsed time).

Comment: How much time does this take anyways in the serial version?  Spinning up threads takes times.  I would not suspect it to be to much time but if the serial version is really fast it might matter.

Comment: @4386427 - It turns out that the sum is incorrect when the thread count is 3, but not by much. It's probably an error with the way I calculate the sum, I don't think it's related to the core issue of speed.

Comment: @NathanOliver Approximately 3 seconds serial version, 6 seconds multithreaded.

Comment: @Daniel yeah, your loop doesn't account for the remainder of an uneven division, but the overall the time crunch shouldn't matter. A ported version of your code for C++11 [can be found here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/947e626954c4adee). Coliru has a limit on hardware concurrency of 2, so test it on your box. Interesting question; have an uptick.

Comment: @WhozCraig When I run the code you linked I get a speed of 350ms for 1 thread and 196ms for 8 threads.

Comment: Maybe the loop in the worker threads could be optimized (the calculation `i <= x + UPPER / NUM` in each step compares to the summing calculation itself). So, the first and last value could be calculated before the loop, and the condition in the for loop would then only be check against the last value, ie avoid the addition (and the division?). And as a sidenote, it would be best that the splitting of the workload be done by the main thread, just for the case that UPPER isn't exactly divisible by NUM (the worker threads should then take a from-to range as a parameter, not the thread ordinal).

Comment: Of topic: I'm not a windows guy so this might be all wrong. I just want to ask: Is CriticalSection really the way to do this on windows? From embedded systems I know that CriticalSection means more or less a complete stop of everything else. Don't windows have simple mutexes?

Comment: @4386427, yes, a critical section is essentially a "mutex", but its a lot faster than a WinAPI mutex object, and only works for threads of the same process. There are other ways to do this, eg the std::mutex.

Comment: In this case, what you're doing inside the critical section is so simple that it can be done without one: see the InterlockedAdd function.  It might be worth making that change just to see how it affects the timing.

Comment: Exactly. Full on lock is way over the top. Atomic arithmetic is the way.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that represent potential culprits.

First of all (and this is usually the big one), check which Compiler Optimizations you have enabled. Two things are often extremely true when it comes to Compiler Optimizations:

- They are very good at optimizing "Accumulation loops", which is what you're doing in this code. In fact, depending on the compiler, they may unroll the loop, or use SIMD operations to speed the whole thing up.
- They are not [as-] good at optimizing any kind of multithreaded code, regardless of how simple the code is.

I've found similar results when dealing with single vs multithreaded accumulators, and the results usually reverse (to the multithreaded code becoming faster) when the optimizations are turned off.

As a case study, consider writing code that's slightly less trivial than "add all numbers together between `x` and `y`" and see if the multithreaded code suddenly becomes more efficient. My prediction is that it will, because the compiler will lose ways to optimize the Serial code.

Secondly, while this usually doesn't represent a huge problem for most use-cases (probably not yours), it's worth noting that starting up new threads usually involves a certain amount of overhead. That's worth bearing in mind.

The last suggestion is to evaluate exactly *how* you're performing the calculations. If you had written code like this:

```
size_t sum = 0;
std::mutex mutex;
std::thread t1([&]{for(size_t i = 0; i < 1'000'000; i++) {mutex.lock(); sum+=i; mutex.unlock();}});
std::thread t2([&]{for(size_t i = 1'000'000; i < 2'000'000; i++) {mutex.lock(); sum+=i; mutex.unlock();}});
t1.join();
t2.join();
std::cout << "Sum of integers between 0 and 1999999: " << sum << std::endl;
```

It would almost certainly be slower than the code you *did* write, which is functionally identical to:

```
size_t sum = 0;
size_t s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
std::mutex mutex;
std::thread t1([&]{for(size_t i = 0; i < 1'000'000; i++) {s1 += i;} mutex.lock(); sum += s1; mutex.unlock();});
std::thread t2([&]{for(size_t i = 1'000'000; i < 2'000'000; i++) {s2 += i;}mutex.lock(); sum += s2; mutex.unlock();});
t1.join();
t2.join();
std::cout << "Sum of integers between 0 and 1999999: " << sum << std::endl;
```

You *might* (emphasis on the word "might") be able to get a minor speed up if you write it like this instead (since Mutexes/Critical Sections are usually major performance bottlenecks):

```
size_t sum = 0;
size_t s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
std::thread t1([&]{for(size_t i = 0; i < 1'000'000; i++) {s1 += i;}});
std::thread t2([&]{for(size_t i = 1'000'000; i < 2'000'000; i++) {s2 += i;}});
t1.join();
t2.join();
sum = s1 + s2;
std::cout << "Sum of integers between 0 and 1999999: " << sum << std::endl;
```

Of course, that's not a huge problem in this situation, but it's always worth considering and bearing in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Spooling up threads is costly.

I would wager though that the biggest influence on run time in this case is compiler optimization and branch prediction. both of which will be significantly better in the serial version in this use case.

Comment: I had the same thought and asked the OP how much time it actually took.  He states the serial version takes 3 seconds and the parallel takes 6.  I'm doubtful it takes 3 seconds to spin up 10 threads.

Comment: Branch prediction will be almost identical in either version. You will have *<number of threads>* branch misses. Compare that to the number of iterations, and you'll see, that this is hardly even measurable.

Comment: @NathanOliver certainly, the initial spin up wont take that long, but for a trivial task such as this, it is still worth considering the overhead of a threaded approach.

Comment: @jhbh - If total time is 3 sec for the serial, a threaded solution should perform better.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple threads accessing a single shared piece of memory with a lock around it.  All that locking, unlocking, context switching, cache hitting, etc adds up in time.  A serial loop in a single thread doesn't have to worry about that.

I just recently watched a video (I'll try to find it and post it here) that explains a similar setup to yours and shows how giving each thread its own dedicated memory to operate on, and then accumulating the calculated values after the threads have finished running, can offer some significant improvements in performance.

Try something more like this:

```
const LONGLONG UPPER = 1000000000;
const int NUM = 10; // number of threads

struct threadInfo
{
    LONGLONG start;
    LONGLONG sum;
};

DWORD WINAPI SumThread(PVOID pvParam) {
    struct threadInfo* pInfo = (struct threadInfo*) pvParam;
    LONGLONG i, sum = 0, x = pInfo->start;

    x *= (UPPER / NUM);

    for (i = x + 1; i <= x + UPPER / NUM; ++i) {
        sum += i;
    }

    pInfo->sum = sum;
    return 0;
}

struct threadInfo* pInfo = (struct threadInfo*) malloc (sizeof(struct threadInfo) * NUM);

HANDLE* hThreads = (HANDLE*) malloc(sizeof(HANDLE) * NUM);

for (int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
    pInfo[i].start = i;
    hThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SumThread, &pInfo[i], 0, NULL);
}

WaitForMultipleObjects(NUM, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);

LONGLONG sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
    sum += pInfo[i].sum;
    CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);
}

free(pInfo);
free(hThreads);
```

Comment: So your suggestion is just eliminate the Critical Section locking? Don't think this will do anything, as entering the critical section only 10 times plus one (yes, even that `g_sum = 0;` command the OP put in his main thread should have been put in a critical section as well) isn't really a big overhead, it's not even measurable actually.